# Unable to open office files from SharePoint 2013 using mobile phone

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

We are seeing weird issue where users are not able to open any office file from their mobile. They are trying to access them through SharePoint 2013 Intranet site which can be accessed through VPN.

Users can able to browse sites, but cannot open the office files and this is for entire farm.

When we open document the browser screen shows blank and sits in there and do nothing.

Not sure what changes caused this issue, it used to work fine properly.

I verified OWA server and it seems to be working fine. and I even changed library settings to "open document using client apps".

Comment: Can you open other types of files like txt or pdf? Have you switched network or browser? Maybe you can try using SharePoint Mobile App and see if it helps.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/supporting-the-sharepoint-mobile-apps-online-and-on-premises

Answer (score 0):

Change to library to Open in Browser, not client apps, OWA is browser based.  Also can a PC on the VPN open documents in OWA?  If not it maybe a network issue where the OWA server is not accessible through the VPN.